# Linebreak in plain text emails, how to do that?

Tags: javascript, email, outlook

I need to send some of my HTML mails as plain text, and to do this I replace 
 with \r\n

```
    returnText=returnText.replace(/<br>/gi, "\r\n");
```

I also tried only to replace with \n but it gives the same result.

When I look at my string after the replace it looks like this:

```
"body": "Hej Torben\r\nBetal venligst den vedlagte faktura for dit ophold på Ananya. \r\nNår du har foretaget betalingen, send venligst et scan eller foto af overførslen, så jeg kan bekræfte betalingen og sende dig en officiel kvittering. \r\nMange tak :-) \r\nVis Booking: http://localhost:9001/book/HYAR4/ (http://localhost:9001/book/HYAR4/)\r\nHilsen from Sunny Thailand :-)\r\nMs. Note Lekpradit\r\nExecutive Property Manager\r\n"....
```

This is all good until I send the mail...

In Gmail looks like this:

[image]

And in outlook it looks like this:

[image]

No matter what I do it completely ignores the \r\n

So I am a bit stuck - cause if I view the mail source it does make nice line breaks, but all the mail readers does not display them

Anyone got an idea here?  Do I use  or something like that?  I cant seem to find a solution here.

This is now I send the email

```
    options = {
        html        : mailRecord.body,
        text        : bodyText,
        subject     : mailRecord.subject,
        from_email  : "info@thaihome.org",
        from_name   : "Note Lekpradit",
        to          : [{
            "email" : mailRecord.user,
            "name"  : usersRecord.name,
            "type"  : "to"
        }],
        headers     : {
            "Reply-To" : "note@thaihome.co.uk"
        },
        important   : false,
        track_opens : true,
        track_clicks: true,
        auto_text   : null,
        auto_html   : null,
        inline_css  : null,
        tags: [
            mailRecord.template
        ]
    }

        mandrill_client.messages.send({"message": options, "async": false}, function(res) {
            show({res});
            return resolve(res);
        }, function(e) {
            criticalLog("mailSend", "MANDRILL ERROR " + e.name+ " - " + e.message, options, 0)
            show('A mandrill error occurred: ' + e.name + ' - ' + e.message);
            return reject(e);
        });
```

Comment: What's your email header html or plain text?

Comment: Sounds like email mime is html not text. Send both types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set  `Content-Type: text/plain` since `\r\n` will not display newline on `text/html` MIME type.

**Update**

- `options.html` : for html messages
- `options.text` : for plain text

Comment: Cool Shalitha - how would you put that into a mail?

Comment: how do you send mail with js? using mail API?

Comment: Yes let me update the task - perhaps you can get an idea where I should put it.

Comment: @torbenrudgaard are you using `text` or `html` property on options to send the email?

Comment: Found it!! - turns out in order to use mandrill to send text mails you have to blank the HTML field in their API or it wont work :)

Comment: once I did that, I got the correct content-type like you wrote